# Preferred method to discuss wiki changes?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On other wiki's I've contributed to, there is often a discussion method. I'm happy to help with changes, but being new to ROS I second guess whether or not these changes would be helpful or even accurate. Is this site appropriate, should I be doing this on the [discussion forums](https://discourse.ros.org/), other?

---

As an example, I stumbled on [this question about `ROS_INFO_STREAM`](http://answers.ros.org/question/10823/ros_info_stream/) and actually don't think it's a horrible question in principle. I'm quite new, and was looking for a handy equivalence table between `ROS_VERBOSITY_TYPE` and equivalent `rospy.logVerbosity()` calls using [python](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Logging). In looking through the wiki on [logging](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging), I think it would help to provide the base format up front:

`ROS_VERBOSITY_TYPE`

As it is, a beginner has to figure out that `DEBUG` in all of the examples could be any of the other verbosity levels. Also, I noticed that the intro says:

> roscpp uses the rosconsole package to provide its client-side API. That API takes the form of a number of `ROS_` macros:

> rosconsole provides four different types of logging statements, at 5 different verbosity levels, with both printf- and stream-style formatting.

I *think* the "types" are what are spelled out next, but this yields a list much longer than 4: **base, named, conditional, conditional named, once, throttle, delayed throttle, filter.**

I could make various changes to remedy this... but it helps to have confirmation that I'm not just experiencing noob confusion and the things that don't make sense are legitimate. Thanks for any suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261473/preferred-method-to-discuss-wiki-changes?/) by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2017-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think [discourse.ros.org](http://discourse.ros.org) would be a good place to discuss these sort of things.

Moinmoin doesn't have the "talk" or "discuss" capabilities like MediaWiki, so that being absent, and ROS Answers really being more of a Q&A site, `discourse.ros.org` seems like a it is the only option.

PS: thanks for making the effort of first discussing things btw. MO has most of the times been to just change things. Perhaps exactly because of a lack of of a place to discuss these kind of things.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2017-05-10**:
Thanks for clarifying. Is there someone who could be contacted about the idea of putting a wiki subforum in place? I contribute to arch linux and it [has one](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewforum.php?id=13) for example. I think the "Site Feedback" section could work for this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-10**:
I think it's ok to put it in the general category for now. The approach has been to propose new categories only when enough posts around a certain topic start to accumulate.

Not sure about whether *Site Feedback* would be a good category.